# How to define an AngularJS function inline (in HTML)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my **HTML page** I have this function:

```
    <button ng-controller="getURL" ng-href="{{getLoginUrl}}">Login</button>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getURL($scope) {
            $scope.getLoginUrl = '/my-url';
        }
    </script>
```

In my **js/app.js** I have the controller with my function `getURL()` defined in inline HTML:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('getURL',['$scope',getURL])
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getURL is not defined

and all the controllers that I put after getURL controller do not work, and I get error `Argument 'anotherController' is not a function, got undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move function declaration before `app.js`, because you are trying use function before declaration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getURL($scope) {
       $scope.getLoginUrl = '/my-url';
   }
</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```